# How to save modified tilemap for level editor app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, tile

I'm making a map editor app for iOS. I can't seem to find any information on how to save a modified tilemap, though. I'm using cocos2d-v3 for my framework.

Does someone have any ideas on how this is done?

Thanks

Comment: You could look at how cocos2d parses a .tmx file to make tilemaps, and then reverse the process. Dunno if it is the same with v3, but you could look at CCTMXXMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

You could port the TMX writer of Kobold Kit: https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/tree/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/TilemapModel/TMX

It actually originates from the KoboldTouch project for cocos2d-iphone, dependencies on the engine is minimal for the entire tilemap model. However there's no renderer for this model available for cocos2d (except in KoboldTouch), and cocos2d's own renderer does not retain all of the tmx information in memory, and certainly not in a way that makes it easy to write back.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the TMXGenerator class for this.  It was written specifically to do that kind of thing.  It's a little dated (pre v3, I haven't tried it with the new source), but it will get you most, if not all, of what you need.

https://github.com/slycrel/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop/Extensions/TMXGenerator